# Deploying that utilises .Net Reactive Extensions

Tags: system.reactive

Our application utilises Reactive Extensions (Rx).  These are normally installed via the downloadable package from Microsoft.  However, when we ship our application we supply copies of the dlls (namely System.CoreEx.dll and System.Reactive.dll).  There appear to be two versions in the GAC v1.0.2787.0 and v1.0.2856.0.  We are referencing a specific one and ship the appropriate versions.

However when the application launches it throws an error dialog which states the Rx Dlls must be installed in the GAC.  It also requests the Dlls for the other version of Rx e.g. if you are referencing 1.0.2787 it will request 1.0.2856.0 and vice versa.

Has anyone got around this problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Rx assemblies don't need to be installed into the GAC unless your application's assemblies are installed in the GAC. Does your application need to be installed in the GAC or can it run from the installation directory?

> It also requests the Dlls for the other version of Rx e.g. if you are referencing 1.0.2787 it will request 1.0.2856.0 and vice versa

It's unlikely that it's actually requesting across versions of Rx. You might want to double/triple check that your solution (*all* projects) all reference the correct (and same) version of the Rx assemblies.

Comment: Thanks Rich - the application isn't in the GAC.  Checked all projects referenced the same version and hey presto seems to resolve the problem. :)

Comment: Glad to have helped. If you want, you can mark the question as "the answer" by clicking the tick on the left. That way, the question won't appear as "unanswered".